# Review Queues > Suggested edits with bug

Tags: bug, status-completed, review-queues, suggested-edits

Today I've done my limit of 20 suggested edits around 8 hours ago. Still, when I came back online around 8 hours later, I was allowed to do more.

I'm not sure if the previous info is relevant to this as can't remember if that problem was already there in the morning.

So, basically the area where it should show when the user proposed the edit is appearing with code, as you can see in the following image:

[image: bug]

For instance:

```
proposed <span title="2019-01-29 19:41:48Z" class="relativetime">53 mins ago</span>
```

instead of:

> proposed Jan 29 '19 at 19:41

What can I do to fix this?

Comment: I also have that <span element there. I don't think it is related to the number of review since I didn't do any in the last 24h. What you did was perfect. Report it here as a bug, then the SO team can take care of it.

Comment: When I went to go look at an edit just on a regular post where the [edit approved] link usually is there was `<a href="/suggested-edits/4116330">edit approved</a> 7 mins ago`

Comment: It's broken network-wide. [MSE report](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/323136/edit-approved-links-are-showing-as-plain-text)

Comment: I just noticed it and came looking to see if there was already a bug report, looks like you've got us covered :)

Comment: I also posted it at Tezos Stack Exchange private beta

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[status-completed](/questions/tagged/status-completed) now. The site mods were working on a few changes but they did a accidental mistake on this change and now they've fixed it!